# "Box With No Top" Optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am having some trouble with this problem,

> A box with no top is to be constructed from a piece of cardboard of dimensions $A$ by $B$ by cutting out squares of length $h$ from the corners and folding up the sides as in the figure below. Suppose that the box height is $h = 1 \text{ inch}$ and that it is constructed using $186$ $\text{ inches}^2$ of cardboard (i.e., $AB = 186$). Which values $A$ and $B$ maximize the volume?
>
> [image]

**My Attempt:**

We have, 
$$SA=AB+1(A+B)=AB+2A+2B=186.$$

Solving for $A$,

$$A=(186-2B)/(B+2).$$

Now, use this to calculate the volume,

$$\begin{align} V &= ABH \\
       &= AB \cdot 1 \\
       &= AB \\
       &= \left( \frac{186-2B}{b+2} \right) B. \\
\end{align}$$

Differentiating with respect to $B$,

$$\frac{dV}{dB} = \dfrac{-2(B^2+4B-186)}{(b+2)^2}.$$

Setting $\frac{dV}{dB}$ equal to zero and solving for $B$ yields,

$$B= -2-\sqrt{190} \ \text{ or } \ B = \sqrt{190}-2.$$

**However, neither of these solutions seem to be correct. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To allow us to provide the most useful answers, please show us what you've tried already. Also, if a diagram is needed to understand the problem, you'd best include it. As it is, we have no way to even guess.

Comment: Are you sure that that is incorrect? I agree with you that both the length and width should be $-2 + \sqrt{190}$, making the surface area $186$ and volume about $138.864$.

Comment: Unless there's a problem in the code of my online Math Homework forum, it's incorrect. I'm wondering if I just set it up wrong in the first place.

Comment: I tried it independently and agree with you. Are you sure you typed it in correctly? Maybe someone else can take a look at this...

Comment: The question says $AB=186$'  your first equation says...?

Comment: You state "$V=A B H$". This is incorrect, the correct equation is $V=(A-2H)(B-2H)H$.

Comment: Even using the V= (A-2H)(B-2H)H, we get the same results for B.

Comment: Your equation for A in terms of B is wrong.  Look closely at the diagram, especially the corners where A and B end, and realize that even if you cut out the squares, you've still "used" the entire sheet of cardboard...

Comment: My homework set just closed, and the program offered this solution:

Comment: @BL - I get a different result. Your notation is difficult to follow, and seems inconsistent.

Comment: "With h=1 and AB=186 (which means that B=186/A), the volume of the box is: 
V(A)=1(A- 2)((186/(A)-2) = 190-2A-(372)/A

where 2≤A≤93

Now, solving V'(A)= -2+(372/(A^2)) = 0 yields A= 13.6382.
Because V(2) = V(93) = 0 and  V(13.6382)= 135.447, maximum volume is achieved with A=B= 13.6382 inches.

Answer (score 1):

The volume is $(A-2)(B-2)$. We want to maximize this given $AB=186$.

Now $(A-2)(B-2)=AB-2(A+B)+4=190-2(A+B)$. We want to minimize $A+B$, which is $A+\frac{186}{B}$. The minimum exists, at a place in "the middle." So the derivative there is $0$. Now it's over: we get the expected $A=B=\sqrt{186}$.