# Maximum volume of a box with a lid that can be made out of a square

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, optimization

Snacks will be provided in a box with a lid (made by removing squares from each corner of a rectangular piece of card and then folding up the sides)

[image: box]

You have a piece of cardboard that is 40cm by 40 cm – what dimensions would give the  maximum volume?

---

This is how I attempted it

Let the length of the square to be cut off be x cm.
V be the Volume in cm3
Volume = L x B x H

$$L= 40 – 2x$$
$$B= 40 – 2x$$
$$H = x$$
So Volume $= x(40-2x)(40-2x)$
$$V = 4X^3 – 160x^2 + 1600x$$
Or $V= x^3 – 40x^2 + 400x$
$$V'  = 3x^2 – 80x + 400$$
$$V'' = 6x – 80$$
Solve for turning points by putting $V ' = 0$

$$3x^ 2 – 80x + 400 = 0 $$

$$(3x - 20)(x – 20) = 0$$

$x= 20/3$ and  $x = 20$

For Max Volume, $x = 20$ is a reasonable solution that can be apply  and discard the other root i.e. $x = 20$

2nd derivative test  $x = 20/3$:

$$V'' = 6(20/3) – 80= -20 < 0 $$ it will give Maximum Volume

$$V =  (20/3)3 – 40(20/3)2 + 400(20/3)$$

$$V = 1186 \text{cm}^ 3$$

Have I done it right ?

Comment: Here's a similar problem.  You can do a search for maximize box corners or something similar. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464047/box-with-no-top-optimization

Comment: The technique is right; the formula for $B$ is wrong - look at the picture, also, you can't divide the volume by 4 (your reasoning escapes me there)

Comment: hmm thank you for the feedback, I thought as x cm is taken of from each side so it will be 2x deducted from each side .. and so I did it that way :D

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
l&=40-2x\\
b&=\frac{40-2x}{2}\\
&=20-x\\
h&=x\\
V&=lbh\\
&=(40-2x)(20-x)x\\
&=800x-80x^2+2x^3\\
V'&=800-160x+6x^2\\
&=2(x-20)(3x-20)
\end{align}$$

By observation, the root at $x=20$ gives $b=0$ so $V=0$, so this clearly can't be the maximum.

That leaves $x=\frac{20}{3}$, where $V=3,555.5$.

For completeness, you should also check the boundaries - these may be the maximum within the domain even though they are not maximas. $x=20$ we have dealt with, $x=0$ falls over because $h=0$.